# React-select default value is not being translated with React-i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-select

I have set up Select component as follow

```
                <Select
                    styles={customStyles}
                    defaultValue={{ label: t('Text to be translated'), value: 'all' }}
                    components={{
                       IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                        }}
                    isSearchable={isSearchable}
                    options={[
                       { value: 'val1', label: t('text 1') },
                       { value: 'val2', label: t('text 2') },
                       { value: 'val3', label: t('text 3') },
                   ]}
                   onChange={handleSelectChange}
                   isDisabled={disabled}
                />
```

my `defaultValue` is translated only on first load of component. Changing language does not affect in any ways. Text is show in language that was chosed on initial load. But fun fact - options are translated with no problem at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass key as parameter to your Select element. Make sure that it's unique value, `label` from `defaultValue` good for it I think. Quote from official documentation below

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: I used `value` as props instead of `defaultValue`

Comment: @SalmaGomaa, nice if that approach worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Just use i18n "ON" handler. More in documentation https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onlanguagechanged

> onLanguageChanged i18next.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {})
>
> Gets fired when changeLanguage got called.

```
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const options = [
    { label: t("Text to be translated"), value: "all" },
    { value: "val1", label: t("text 1") },
    { value: "val2", label: t("text 2") },
    { value: "val3", label: t("text 3") },
  ];

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0]);

  i18n.on("languageChanged", () => {
    if (selectedOption.value === "all")
      setSelectedOption({ label: t("Text to be translated"), value: "all" });
  });
```

Also don`t forget to pass **selectedOption as value prop** and **use setSelectedOption in onSelectHandler**.